# How can I compile and run a Java program?

Tags: java, compilation

How can I compile and run a Java program?

Comment: Are you using an IDE ? Are you using a plain text editor ?

Comment: What type of Java program do you want to run? There are many, and the details of how things work as a webapp, or a GUI app, or a server, or an applet in a webpage, or an app in a mobile phone... these are all different. Compilation is also diverse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run and compile java program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265630/how-to-run-and-compile-java-program)

Answer (score 4):

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html#win32-2b

Is English difficult for you?  There are tutorials for your language too.

Answer (score 2):

to compile:

> javac path/to/file/with/main.java

then to run:

> java path/to/file/with/main

Comment: Um, no. java takes a class name in foo.bar.baz.ClassName syntax, not a pathname of a .class file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that if you are starting with the java language, first use an IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans, Intellij IDEA or another. For a first step let the IDE do his job. Then once you evolve quickly use a build manager (Ant, Maven, Gradle, ...). It is a good practice to always have a build manager in place to keep the build in control.

Answer (score 0):

To compile (assuming you are in the same folder as the file is)

```
javac "filename.java"
```

To run

```
java "filename"
```

make sure you have set the environment variables correctly, so that the command line can detect where javac is.