# How to run and compile java program?

Tags: java, compilation

I am compiling a simple program

```
class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
     }
}
```

I typed in command prompt `java Test.java`, but it did not work.

> Could not find or load main class Test.java

I'm not using any IDE. Where should I place the program file on my computer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot directly run a java source file. You need to compile it first using `javac`:

```
javac Test.java
```

Then you get a .class file that you can run:

```
java Test
```

Comment: my program is class Test
{
public static void main (String args[])
{
System.out.println("Hello");
}
}

Comment: i now get error Error: Could not find or load main class Test.class

Comment: @user1491648: so you have that code in a file called Test.java?

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class test. still error exists. i placed my program file on desktop. is it ok

Comment: @user1491648: Very strange because I just tested all this and it works correctly for me.

Comment: i installed java sdk. and wrote program in notepad and try to ran it. this is my first program

Comment: when i type javac Test.java , i get error 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @user1491648: Aaah then that is the problem. You need to add the bin folder of the java sdk to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Ok so right-click `My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables`. There you will find the list of environment variables (the bottom list). Find the `Path` variable, click edit and at the end add a `;` and the path to the bin folder of your jdk installation (should be in program files somewhere).