# Run java file from outside its directory

Tags: java

I am stuck in to a basic problem of java. I need to run a java file from a shell. Please see below for the scenario.

Java file resides in com.abc.foo.test.Execution.java
Shell file to execute the java file resides in the same location.

Now from outside(Any location) I need to execute the shell file and the shell file will execute my java program.

Comment: So what is the problem ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265630/how-to-run-and-compile-java-program?rq=1

Comment: I can execute the java program from the root directory, but not from inside the package where SH is. Is that possible to run the java with that sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you want is a command-line script.

You should try this:

```
java -classpath directory_to_java_file
```

But why is the shell file in the same directory as the java file? You want to run the java file from outside using the shell file, right?

Comment: R u meaning
java -classpath com.abc.foo.test.Execution

Comment: You need to include the directory to the java file, too. For example, C:/directory_to_java_file/com.abc.foo.test.Execution.java